# jquery undelegate help

Tags: jquery

I have elements dynamically added to the div 'wrap', such as:

```
<div id='wrap'>
    <div id="one">apple</div>
    <div id="two">pear</div>
</div>
```

The child divs have click events that go to an ajax call.

```
$('#wrap').delegate('div', 'click', getInfo);
```

I want to undelegate the click event from the specific div that was clicked.  In other words, if div#one is clicked, the event is undelegated from div#one but remains delegated on div#two.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class to clicked `div`s that would end up filtering them out in the future:

```
$('#wrap').delegate('div:not(.clicked)', 'click', function(event) {
    // You could just add this to getInfo instead of calling it from the handler:
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    getInfo.call(this, event); 
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/7EpSK/

Answer (score 3):

Because the [`delegate()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method  uses event delegation, there's only one handler assigned to the container `#wrap` that handles all the click events that bubble up to it.

One solution would be to add a handler to the clicked element that prevents the event from bubbling.

```
$('#wrap').delegate('div', 'click', getInfo);

function getInfo() {
    $(this).bind('click',false);
    // rest of the code
}
```

This will bind a handler to the element that was clicked. The handler does nothing but prevents propagation of the event (and prevents the default behavior, but for a `<div>` there is no default behavior).

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/mzvHK/

Answer (score 0):

THis is not a direct answer just more of an alternative:

the jQuery `.one()` will give you an event that fires only once per element:

```
$('#wrap div').one('click', getInfo);
```

reference: http://api.jquery.com/one/